# How to add the UI for one of the tab controller's using loadView when the rest were via Interface Builder?

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller

I have a main window which has the UITabViewController as its root controller. I am using a nib file for this. In Interface Builder, two of the tabs have been wired to Controller_A, Nib_A and Controller_B, Nib_B but the 3rd tab only knows about Controller_C.

I assumed that this would mean that the loadView method of Controller_C would be automatically called since I haven't bothered to specify the NIB file. I want to lay this piece out programmatically. And it DOES indeed get called as I've confirmed by placing a breakpoint inside this method.

BUT when I switched over to Controller_C in the simulator, it comes up empty!

Here's what the loadView of Controller_C looks like:

```
- (void)loadView
{
    [super loadView];
    ...
    [self setTableView:formTableView];
    [view addSubview:formTableView];
    [self setView:view];
}
```

Any tips? What am I ignoring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems loadView works as expected, the reason that my view was blank is because the datasource for my tableview was actually NIL. Earlier, I did not consider this scenario as I thought that it would at least present an empty table in such a case but apparently that was an incorrect assumption on my part. All this mistakenly led me to believe that the view wasn't being initialized properly.

@cduhn: Thanks, I had been following steps 1-3 already and it was really good to hear someone else give the same advice. The rest of what you said was educational for me as well.

Thanks Everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are searching for:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
```

Comment: No I don't think so and please correct me if I'm wrong. Here's why I think so: If one does not wish to use initWithNibName then overloading loadView is the other option. Or if I'm right AND you are right too, then please elaborate how?

Comment: I see. Then my answer was incorrect. You can customize the -(void)initWithNibName function and exclude the super, thereby ignoring the xib.

Comment: I tried throwing all my code from loadView into viewDidLoad, same behaviour ... no UI ... I feel like there is something more going on here, my speculation being that the MainWindow.xib file where I configure Controller_C in the right hand side pane ... is probably leading to a situation where the runtime is choosing to call both initWithNibName AND loadView. That would fail because there is no nib file with the same name (i didn't specify one in MainWindow.xib) as my Controller_C and Apple defines the use of both methods as "unpredictable"

Answer (score 0):

Here are the main things to check.

1. Click on your Controller_C in interface builder.  In the Identity Inspector, make sure that the Class field is set to Controller_C.
2. In the Attributes Inspector, make sure the NIB Name field is blank.
3. If you have an existing Controller_C.xib laying around in your project, remove and delete it.  The default implementation of loadView loads this file even if
4. Remove `[super loadView]`.  Since you're building your view hierarchy in code, you shouldn't invoke the default implementation.  You should explicitly allocate the controller's view as a local variable in loadView and set it using `setView:`.

Also, your comment on the other answer suggests that you may be confused about when/why `loadView` and `initWithNibName:bundle:` get called, so let me clarify:

`loadView` gets called to lazy load your controller's view the first time its `view` property gets accessed.  This is true whether your view controller was constructed as an object in a NIB, or whether you constructed it yourself in code using `initWithNibName:bundle:`.  The default implementation of `loadView` loads the NIB that was specified in `initWithNibName:bundle:` or in the NIB Name property in IB.  If a NIB name wasn't specified, the default implementation looks for any NIB in the bundle that has the same name as your class and loads that NIB if one is found.  If no appropriate NIB is found, then the default implementation of `loadView` just creates an empty view and sets that as your controller's view.  When we build our own view hierarchy explicitly in `loadView`, we don't want any of these default behaviors, so we don't call `[super loadView]`.